# Design a email daily digest feature with spring integration

Tags: spring, aggregate, spring-batch, spring-integration

I currently have a SI project that listen on a JMS queue do some processing and depending on the messages send emails, write files, ...

Now I want to add a daily digest feature on the sending emails part. I want email messages to be stored somewhere and that once a day all messages that have the same destination email are grouped, content is concatenated and email is sent.

What would be the best design solution for this?
I checked the aggregator concept but I have few questions:

- I need persistent storage of aggregated messages. Aggregated messages are only sent once a day so I don't want to loose messages. I guess I should use JdbcMessageStore?
- I need transactions from Input queue -> aggregator then another transactions from aggregator to email output. Is this possible and if yes how should I configure?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers

**EDIT**

I now tried as here:

```
<int:aggregator id="templatingDailyAggregator"
    input-channel="templatingDailyAggregatorInputChannel" 
    output-channel="templatingDailyAggregatorOutputChannel"

    message-store="templatingEmailAggregatorStore"
    correlation-strategy-expression="headers['templatingEmailGroupingCategory']+payload.emailMessage.email"
    release-strategy-expression="false"

    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
    >

    <int:expire-transactional transaction-manager="templatingAggregatorStoreTransactionManager"/>
</int:aggregator>

<int-jdbc:message-store id="templatingEmailAggregatorStore" data-source="templatingEmailAggregatorStoreDataSource" />

<bean id="templatingAggregatorStoreTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="templatingEmailAggregatorStoreDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- MySQL DB DataSource -->
<bean id="templatingEmailAggregatorStoreDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="MYURL" />
    <property name="username" value="MYUSER" />
    <property name="password" value="MYPASS" />
</bean>

<bean id="templatingEmailAggregatorStoreReaper" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="templatingEmailAggregatorStore"/>
    <property name="timeout" value="10"/>
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="templatingAggregatorScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="templatingEmailAggregatorStoreReaper" method="run" cron="0 */2 * * * * "/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="templatingAggregatorScheduler"/>

<int:transformer id="templatingDailyDigestTransformer" ref="templatingDailyDigestTransformerBean" input-channel="templatingDailyAggregatorOutputChannel" method="processMessage" output-channel="emailOutputChannel"/>
```

But have the problem that if I have an exception after the aggregation part (e.g. during the sending of the email) I would expect the MessageGroup consumption to be rolled back and thus still be present in the database. However this is not the case the MessageGroup is consumed, is not present in the DB anymore and thus is lost.

**EDIT 2**

I added the transformer after the aggregator in the above XML. Currently this transformer simply raise an exception for testing crashed cases.
Here is the stacktrace I optain:

```
DEBUG [exec-1] - Expiring all messages older than timeout=10 from message group store: org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore@3e082583
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT distinct GROUP_KEY as CREATED from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_BYTES, CREATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID in (SELECT MESSAGE_ID from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY = ?) and REGION=? ORDER BY CREATED_DATE]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning BLOB as bytes
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COMPLETE, LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY = ? and REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_BYTES, CREATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID in (SELECT MESSAGE_ID from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY = ?) and REGION=? ORDER BY CREATED_DATE]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning BLOB as bytes
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COMPLETE, LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY = ? and REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
INFO  [exec-1] - Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey[fb90fe78-c3df-3793-9ee8-acae4924bebe]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Prematurely releasing partially complete group with key [fb90fe78-c3df-3793-9ee8-acae4924bebe] to: templatingDailyAggregatorOutputChannel
DEBUG [exec-1] - Completing group with correlationKey [fb90fe78-c3df-3793-9ee8-acae4924bebe]
DEBUG [exec-1] - org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@2fdde28c received message: GenericMessage [payload=[ch.post.ehealth.extcom.templating.core.PreAggregatorEmailMessage@563b5cce], headers={jms_timestamp=1426090799820, extcomPluginDestination=templatingPluginInputChannel, extcomId=5782d059-c88d-44ae-82a1-0b738b43e821, jms_messageId=ID:some-vm-45363-1421229178337-3:9:1:1:4, timestamp=1426090920046, id=b8330bed-fc74-c8d5-6838-a3116a05ab39, history=jmsInputAdapter,inputChannel,xmlToSpringIntTransformer,pluginRouterChannel,pluginRouter,templatingPluginInputChannel,templatingTransformer,templatingPluginOutputChannel,templatingOutputRouter,templatingEmailOutputChannel,templatingEmailGroupingRouter,templatingPreAggregatorChannel,templatingPreAggregatorTransformer,templatingDailyAggregatorInputChannel,templatingDailyAggregator,templatingDailyAggregatorOutputChannel, JdbcMessageStore.CREATED_DATE=1426090800772, jms_type=, jms_redelivered=false, priority=0, templatingEmailGrouping=DAILY, jms_correlationId=, JdbcMessageStore.SAVED=true, templatingEmailGroupingCategory=DAILY}]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [select MESSAGE_ID, CREATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID in (select MESSAGE_ID from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?) ORDER BY CREATED_DATE]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT MESSAGE_ID, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_BYTES from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning BLOB as bytes
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL update
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [DELETE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - SQL update affected 1 rows
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL update
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [DELETE from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Removing relationships for the group with group key=fb90fe78-c3df-3793-9ee8-acae4924bebe
DEBUG [exec-1] - SQL update affected 1 rows
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL update
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [DELETE from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Marking messages with group key=fb90fe78-c3df-3793-9ee8-acae4924bebe
DEBUG [exec-1] - SQL update affected 1 rows
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
ERROR [exec-1] - Exception in expiry callbackjava.lang.RuntimeException: test crash
    at ch.post.ehealth.extcom.templating.core.DailyDigestTransformer.processMessage(DailyDigestTransformer.java:33) ~[extcom-templating.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:63) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:95) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:44) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:258) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:111) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:164) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:276) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:75) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
Wrapped by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: test crash
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:64) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:68) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
Wrapped by: org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: test crash
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:74) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:248) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:171) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:119) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:657) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:642) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.expireGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:619) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.forceComplete(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:543) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler$ForceReleaseMessageGroupProcessor.processMessageGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:721) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler$1.execute(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:168) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.store.AbstractMessageGroupStore.expire(AbstractMessageGroupStore.java:169) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.store.AbstractMessageGroupStore.expireMessageGroups(AbstractMessageGroupStore.java:113) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper.run(MessageGroupStoreReaper.java:115) [spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) [spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]

DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_BYTES, CREATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID in (SELECT MESSAGE_ID from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE where GROUP_KEY = ?) and REGION=? ORDER BY CREATED_DATE]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COMPLETE, LAST_RELEASED_SEQUENCE, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_DATE from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY = ? and REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Group expiry candidate (fb90fe78-c3df-3793-9ee8-acae4924bebe) has changed - it may be reconsidered for a future expiration
ERROR [exec-1] - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.java.lang.RuntimeException: test crash
    at ch.post.ehealth.extcom.templating.core.DailyDigestTransformer.processMessage(DailyDigestTransformer.java:33) ~[extcom-templating.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:63) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:95) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:44) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:258) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:111) ~[spring-expression-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:164) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:276) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:75) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
Wrapped by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: test crash
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:64) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:68) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
Wrapped by: org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: test crash
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:74) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:248) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:171) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:119) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:657) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:642) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.expireGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:619) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.forceComplete(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:543) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler$ForceReleaseMessageGroupProcessor.processMessageGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:721) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler$1.execute(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:168) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.store.AbstractMessageGroupStore.expire(AbstractMessageGroupStore.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.store.AbstractMessageGroupStore.expireMessageGroups(AbstractMessageGroupStore.java:113) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper.run(MessageGroupStoreReaper.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_71]

DEBUG [exec-1] - Expiring all messages older than timeout=10 from message group store: org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore@3e082583
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG [exec-1] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT distinct GROUP_KEY as CREATED from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP where REGION=?]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [exec-1] - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aggregator]
DEBUG [exec-1] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looks like you go right way.

You can enclose you aggregator to the TX for JMS and JDBC and group messages by desired `correlationKey`, e.g. `correlation-key-expression`.

Since you don't want to `release` groups until some daily event (e.g. cron trigget) you should mark your aggregator with options:

```
release-strategy-expression="false"
send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
```

- the first one: do not allow the normal `release`
- the second: send the aggregator result to the `output-channel`, but not `discard-channel` on `expire`
- the third: remove groups from the `MessageStore` to allow to form the fresh on for the same `correlationKey`

To make it worked you should configure `MessageGroupStoreReaper`:

```
<bean id="reaper" class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="messageStore"/>
    <property name="timeout" value="10"/>
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="reaper" method="run" cron="0 0 * * * * "/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="scheduler"/>
```

The `Reaper` invokes the `MessageGroupCallback` which is registered during aggregator initialization. That callback invokes `forceComplete` on the aggregator to allow to work all those mentioned options.

Starting with SI-4.1 `<aggregator>` supports `<expire-transactional>` sub-element which allow to wrap that `forceComplete` to the TX, like you asked.

Previously we need to wrap to the TX (e.g. using `<tx:advice>`) the `MessageGroupStoreReaper.run()` method.

Hope I am clear.

**UPDATE**

My apologies, I see that we have a bug. In documentation about `<expire-transactional>` we say:

> Allows a transaction to be started for the `forceComplete` operation. It is initiated from a `group-timeout(-expression)` or by a `MessageGroupStoreReaper` and is not applied to the normal `add/release/discard` operations. Only this sub-element or `<expire-advice-chain/>` is allowed.

But it isn't true. The code looks likes:

```
if (this.groupTimeoutExpression != null && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.forceReleaseAdviceChain)) {
    ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(processor);
    for (Advice advice : this.forceReleaseAdviceChain) {
        proxyFactory.addAdvice(advice);
    }
    return (MessageGroupProcessor) proxyFactory.getProxy(getApplicationContext().getClassLoader());
}
```

So, we apply the `<expire-transactional>` only if `group-timeout(-expression)` is provided, but it isn't a case for the `MessageGroupStoreReaper`.

Feel free to raise a JIRA issue on the matter and we'll take care of it soon.

In meanwhile as a work around you should use `<tx:advice>` for the `MessageGroupStoreReaper.run()`.

Comment: Hi I still have a small problem with this solution. If I have an exception after the aggregation part (e.g. during the sending of the email) I would expect the MessageGroup consumption to be rolled back and thus still be present in the database. However this is not the case the MessageGroup is consumed, is not present in the DB anymore and thus is lost. Do you know if there is a way to solve that?

Comment: Well, I see only the case, when `the sending of the email` is done from the separate Thread, not from that which expires message groups

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. Currently the sending is done by the MessageGroupStoreReaper with the scheduler I defined. Do you think I messup somehow my config at some point?

Comment: Good. Do you have `tx:advice` for the rollback case ?

Comment: I set int:expire-transactional on the aggregator as you can see I updated my question with a part of my spring context.

Comment: Good. Show, please, the further downstream flow from the `templatingDailyAggregatorOutputChannel` and, in addition, share logs when you get an exception.

Comment: Added the logs and downstream flow from templatingDailyAggregatorOutputChannel

Comment: Your logs look clear, thanks. Would you mind making the `TRACE` logging config for the `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor` category and update your question with the TX info

Comment: I did it but it doesn't seems I have any logs coming from package "org.springframework.transaction". So I guess there is no transaction involved. That is strange